# How to get a list of the available stack from cloudformation with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, aws-cloudformation

Our team's  application will deploy bunch of stacks and one those stacks is SuperStar that can only exists one per AWS account, therefore Im trying to find out how can our typeScript cdk get the list of stacks from cloudformation. I know there is AWS CLI command `aws cloudformation list-stacks --region us-east-1` but is there any typscript API for it as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listStacks` from aws-sdk: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#listStacks-property. Note that doing so in your aws-cdk code will only check the existence of "SuperStar" when you synthesize your stack, so it's not guaranteed that "SuperStar" will not exist when your stack gets to the deployment stage.